Reference function argument as output property name
Is there a way to express a relationship between a function argument value and a property name in the output type?
Consider this simple method that takes an object and returns a copy that also includes a new property with the given name:
function withZero<T extends {}>(input: T, key: string) {
    return {...input, [key]: 0};
}

I want the return type of this method to be something along the lines of (pseudocode) T & {[key]: number}, i.e. making the type system aware that whatever is passed as the key parameter will become the name of a property of the resulting object.
Example: withZero({foo: "Hello"}, "bar") should be recognized as a type equivalent to {foo: string} & {bar: number}.
Unfortunately, I have not found a way to express such a relationship in TypeScript. Is this possible?

Yes, you can write the output as T & {[P in K]: number} as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate question. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz: This appears to be exactly what I want! If you post it as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

First, your withZero() function needs to be generic in the type K of key, or else key will just be string and then your output would, at best, have a string index signature like {[key: string]: number}.  You want key to possibly be a literal type like "c", so that the type would look like {c: number} instead.
Then you can't write {[key]: number} or {[key: K]: number} directly as an index signature, but you can make it a mapped type of the form {[P in K]: number}. That's also equivalent to Record<K, number> using the Record utility type.
So your output could be of type T & { [P in K]: number}:
function withZero<T extends object, K extends string>(input: T, key: K) {
  return { ...input, [key]: 0 } as T & { [P in K]: number };
}

Note that a type assertion is necessary because TypeScript cannot do anything more useful with the value {[key]: 0} than widening it all the way to {[key: string]: number}; see microsoft/TypeScript#13948.
If we test it, you get the behavior you're looking for:
const x = withZero({ a: "abc", b: 123 }, "c");
//    ^? const x: {a: string, b: number} & {c: number}
console.log(x.c.toFixed(2)) // "0.00"

Note that the type {[P in K]: number} can be inaccurate if K turns out to be wider than a single string literal type.  If it's string or a union like "c" | "d", then the output type would be wrong. There are workarounds for these, but as long as you call withZero where key is a single string literal value known at compile time, then such workarounds are more trouble than they're worth.  You can read microsoft/TypeScript#13948 for more information.
Playground link to code

You can't really do this, because TS is a compile-time type inference system, not a runtime type inference system.
The most you might be able to get away with if you know what these should be at compile time, is something like this:
interface Bar {
    bar: number;
}

function withZero<T extends {}, K extends keyof Bar>(input: T, key: K) {
    return {...input, [key]: 0};
}

const t = withZero({foo: "Hello"}, "bar")
// No type errors

const v = withZero({foo: "Hello"}, "bzar")
// TypeScript is now angry at `bzar` ^

This doesn't really achieve the spirit of what I think you're asking though, because v will still be typed as:
const t: {
    foo: string;
} & {
    [x: string]: number;
}

...so I expect it's not very helpful.
You might get slightly closer to what you want with this, but again, requires you to define the object you're expecting at compile time:
const barKeys = ["bar"] as const;

type Bar = {
  [key in typeof barKeys[number]]: string;
};

const b: Bar = {
  bar: "foo",
  bzar: "fzoo",
  // ^ Now TypeScript won't let you use `bzar` here.
};

const withZero = <T extends {}, K extends keyof Bar>(input: T, key: K): T & Bar => {
    return {...input, [key]: 0} as T & Bar;
}

const result = withZero({
    foo: "foo"
}, "bar");


You can certainly have generic K extends string and have the key be "dynamic" at compile time. I'm also not sure why you'd want T | Bar as an output instead of an intersection.

Good catch @jcalz, intersection is correct. And yes, the key can be dynamic instead, but if I'm understanding OP's intent correctly, that kinda defeats the purpose of having the return type know about the name of the key being returned.
